# How to target/link resources (images and sounds) in vue

Tags: vue.js

I'm using vue-element-admin template (http://panjiachen.github.io/vue-admin-template). With the vue ui I run the dev server while coding.

Where should I store a img or audio file and how do I access it in the test and the live environments?

In the code images are saved under the images on assets

```
<img class="pic-404__parent" src="@/assets/404_images/404.png" alt="404">
```

when I try this

```
<template>
   <img :src="img_url" >
</template>

data: function() {
    return {
      img_url: ''
    }
},
setImage() {
 this.img_url = '@/assets/404_images/404_coloud.png'
}
```

I get this

```
<img src="@/assets/404_images/404_coloud.png">
```

Answer (score 0):

you are assigning a static string value ... you should be using `require` instead :

```js
this.img_url =  require('@/assets/404_images/404_coloud.png')
```

Comment: Sounds plausible, but I can't get this to work. I get "Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@/assets/404_images/404_coloud.png'"

Comment: @HugovanSchalkwyk make sure the path is correct because i just tried it on one of my projects and it works